# Adding Unity's Diagnostic extension in Prism Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, unity-container

I get a Unity.ResolutionFailedException and it hints that I can get more information by adding the Diagnostic extension:

> Unity.ResolutionFailedException: For more information add Diagnostic extension: Container.AddExtension(new Diagnostic())

I've attempted to add the extension in App.xaml.cs' constructor and in RegisterTypes, but neither seems to work (same message).

```cs
public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer)
    : base(initializer)
{
    this.Container.GetContainer().AddExtension(new Diagnostic());
}
```

```cs
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.GetContainer().AddExtension(new Diagnostic());
    ...
```

On http://unitycontainer.org/tutorials/diagnostic.html, it states:

> IMPORTANT
>   Extension methods will not work on IUnityContainer interface. It is only available on the UnityContainer itself.

Which would explain the behavior I am seeing. So is it possible to add the diagnostic extension?

Answer (score 2):

> So is it possible to add the diagnostic extension?

You could just cast to `UnityContainer`:

```
using Prism.Unity; // for the GetContainer extension method

((UnityContainer)containerRegistry.GetContainer()).AddExtension(new Diagnostic());
```

Alternatively, override `PrismApplication.CreateContainerExtension` and add the extension to the container directly:

```
protected override IContainerExtension CreateContainerExtension()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.AddExtension( new Diagnostic() );
    return new UnityContainerExtension( container );
}
```

Comment: Seems pretty straight forward to cast to UnityContainer, but I still get the same exception and statement to add the diagnostics extension and no additional info. Is this what you do in your projects?

Comment: Do not use the first method... the second method shown would be the correct way to do what @Adam is looking to do.

Comment: In fact, I use an older version of prism that doesn't try to hide the container. My clients are regulated and cannot easily update any third party lib, anyway.

Comment: It'd be nice if my edit to your answer (removing the wrong bit) was approved so I could mark it as the solution.

Comment: @Adam I cannot see an edit, I'd happily approve, though. What would you like to remove?

Comment: The first part that does not work. I checked the status of the edit and you rejected on April 7th, stating that it alters your original intent. I guess your intent was to provide two options, one that doesn't work? You can't cast container registry and even on older versions of prism that code doesn't work since there is no `containerRegistry.GetContainer()`

Comment: Noone wants to cast `IContainerRegistry` to `UnityContainer`, of course this does not work. There _is_ an extension method `GetContainer` for each supported container, I'll make an edit to make that clearer.

Comment: Of course you wouldn't cast IContainerRegistry to UnityContainer, that's silly. Calling GetContainer and casting the result to UnityContainer doesn't work either.  Why? I don't know. Seems like it should. Check out Dan Siegel's comment too. I appreciate your answer and discussing this here too by the way.

Comment: Casting the result of `GetContainer` to `UnityContainer` works fine for me. If you don't cast and just assign it to a `var`, you see that it's actually a `UnityContainer`, the cast just sheds the interface. Regarding Dan, he's correct insofar as this is the way recommended by the Prism-team, but it's rather limiting, too, as it can only be used in the app itself. The cast-variant is usable everywhere essentially, including module initializers, so I think it's important to list it, too.